# Switch Case duplicate : Eclipse is telling me that case 014 and case 12 are duplicates

Tags: java, duplicates, switch-statement

```
int var = 12;
        switch (var)
        {
            case 014 :
                System.out.print("Hello");
                break;
            case 12 :
                System.out.print("Hi");
            default :
                System.out.print("How r u?");
        }
```

can anybody please help me understand the logic, How case 014 and case 12 are duplicates ?

Comment: `014===12` Welcome to octal

Comment: octaloverflow! :)